# How to recreate ViewModel instead of reading previous one

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-lifecycle

As we can find in `Google` site, it says:

> If the activity is re-created, it receives the same MyViewModel instance that was created by the first activity. When the owner activity is finished, the framework calls the ViewModel objects's onCleared() method so that it can clean up resources.

So, right now, I do not want that feature. I want to recreate the `ViewModel` each time the `Fragment` gets created. Because I have a reference of the object using the id.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SaleViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SaleViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getSaleLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<SaleEntity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<SaleEntity> saleEntities) {
            initAll();
        }
    });
}
```

Inside `SaleViewModel`, I have the reference of the `Store` (which is set activities before):

```
private static FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
private static DatabaseReference HOT_STOCK_REF = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user.getUid()).child(FirebaseStoreRef.getInstance().getStoreEntity().getId()).child("income");
private FirebaseQueryLiveData liveData = new FirebaseQueryLiveData(HOT_STOCK_REF);
```

With that being said, I need to recreate the `ViewModel` every single time because of the reference I need to refresh (otherwise, I will be getting the first reference set).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should find another way for refreshing your object instead of recreating `ViewModel` instance, or else it's worthless to use **MVVM** in your project if you just recreate your `ViewModels` on configuration changes.

Comment: Why are you using a ViewModel if you don't want it to be saved across configuration changes? Sounds like you just want those objects in your Fragment directly.

Comment: Is not on configuration changes that I want to recreate, is once I finish the activity, change reference of the `Store` and restart those fragments, there is where I want to recreate instances of `ViewModels`.

Comment: @Amg91 If you only want the `ViewModel` to persist the same time as the `Fragment` then scope it to the fragment. Why scope it to the activity?

Comment: "is once I finish the activity, change reference of the Store and restart those fragments, there is where I want to recreate instances of ViewModels. " -- that happens automatically. `ViewModelProviders.of(this)` will return different `ViewModel` instances for different values of `this`.